# Android Softkeyboard enter the numeric value into edittext very slow

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I have TableLayout, which contain number of products.Each row contain code, description qty , price, discount value, ..... Depends on the user enter quantity , discount value, discount quantity & some other values also will calculate.

when user click on the editText soft keyboard will come this one also ok, working fine

My problem is when user press numeric keys very slow to show in the EditText.

For example I have press 3 from keyboard, after 7 or 8 seconds only it show in that particular editText.How can I reduce this time line...

This is my product image:

[image: ProductImage]

Please Anybody suggest why this happening?

Code like this :

```
     for (int i = initil; i <end; i++) {
        .............
        ............
        final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
            txtQty.setHeight(1);
            txtQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 42));
            txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            txtQty.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            txtQty.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            txtQty.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            txtQty.setTextSize(9);
            txtQty.setHint("0.0");
    //      txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
//          txtQty.setHighlightColor(R.color.green);
            tr.addView(txtQty); 

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showSoftInput(txtQty, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            mgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtQty.getWindowToken(), 0);

            txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
                    .............................
        } });
```

Comment: check with reducing rows in tablelayout,......

Comment: Have you checked on the real device..?

Comment: @Viv currently first page contain 10 records. i can't reduce more because some clients have more than 400 records. so that.If we decalre out side of the loop , is it possible to get the rows value outside? (I think no). If we declare outside then its ok.

Comment: @LalitPoptani I have checked in real device also.That one also same issue. Because of the problem listener method is inside the loop.First page(pagination) contain 10 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this code for Dynamic tablelayout :

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#C0C0C0">

  <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="20dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#C0C0C0">

   <TableLayout android:id="@+id/contact_table"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/contact_info_title"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/bgwhite_selector">
      </TableLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

To add Contents of TableLayout use this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"         android:id="@+id/lays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"> 

<TableRow    android:background="@color/white" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView   android:text=">" 
            android:textSize="18dip" android:textStyle="bold"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/arrowText"/> 
  </TableRow>

 </LinearLayout>
```

After you created sepearate rows for layouts add this in Java code :

```
contact_table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.contact_table);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

for(int i = 0; i < contact_count ; i++) {
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row,contact_table, false);
TextView text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(list_data.get(i).summary);
contact_table.addView(row);
  }

 for(int i=0;i<contact_table.getChildCount();i++){ 
final View row=contact_table.getChildAt(i);
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        row_id=contact_table.indexOfChild(row);
    }
});
}
```

Second for is the loop getting the click of Dynamically created Table row , in that add the

```
    msg_title_text.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
```

Corresponding Action listener :

```
    class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Log.v("*****************************", "Clicked");

            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some slowness but this reduce the time comparing with my previous code. Thanks @Venky

Comment: @Venky I have 3 columns in my table, my doubt is how can I stretch my second column using this approach?