# TableLayout with fixed section header and scrollable

Tags: android, tablerow, android-tablelayout, sectionheader, tableheader

I am trying to create a view like this:

[image: Table layout]

...that has two fixed headers. Whole table layout is scrollable and inner table view is also scrollable as shown in image. Headers and data are dynamic. And when I scroll up to header-2 it hides items of header-1 not header-1.

Comment: why not trying two `tableviews` with fixed labels for header inside one `scrollview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain how you can accomplish it easily **without using ListView**. For less amount of data you should not use ListView it will affects your efficiency.

**Step 1 :**

Make use of weight attribute and give equal half for two header

**Step 2:**

Headers name be static , create one TableLayout inside Scroll View

**Step 3:**

Create TableRow as dynamic is separate or in same Layout and dynamically add Table row into the TableLayout.

Repeat the same for the Second Header you will get.

[For Dynamic TableLayout check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683154/android-softkeyboard-enter-the-numeric-value-into-edittext-very-slow)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="list1" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#FF4500" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="list2" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/con_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to maintain an adapter class. so that you can align the elements as u need

check [this](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/).

and [this](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/11/android-listview-header-two-or-more-in.html)