# Adding a tablerow using inflator in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I am trying to add table rows to a table using layout inflator.

Here is my XML file,called customlistviewitem.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="75dp">
  <TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/myTableLayout1">

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code I am using to add rows to the table

```
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout1);
            LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                //Log.e("Carlist","Result" +result);
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   int ct_id = json_data.getInt("id");
                   String make = json_data.getString("make");
                   String model = json_data.getString("model");
                   String price = json_data.getString("price");

                   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                         tr.setId(ct_id);
                         tr.setClickable(true);

                         tr.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final View v) {

                                    String sdet_id;
                                    int det_id;
                        //          v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                    det_id = v.getId();
                                    sdet_id = String.valueOf(det_id);
                                    final Intent i = new Intent();
                                    i.setClassName("demo.example.com", "demo.example.com.cardetails");
                                    i.putExtra("Det_id", sdet_id);
                                    startActivity(i);

                          //        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }
                            });
                         TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                              new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                              (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            int leftMargin=20;
                            int topMargin=10;
                            int rightMargin=15;
                            int bottomMargin=20;

                            tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

                            tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

                              /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
                         ImageView myimage = new ImageView(this);

                         BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
                        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
                        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
                        myimage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                         tr.addView(myimage);
                         TextView tmake=new TextView(this);
                        // tmake.setText(make);
                         tmake.setText(Html.fromHtml("<H1>" + make));
                         tr.addView(tmake); 

                         TextView tmodel=new TextView(this);
                         tmodel.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><H1>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "€" + price + "</b></H1></br></br>" ));
                         tr.addView(tmodel);



                    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
                     //  tr.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
                         tl.addView(tr);
                         View v = new View(this);
                         v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                         tl.addView(v);

            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is not adding the table row. What do I need to do to add the row and the text items?

Comment: [Check this post for dynamic table row inside tablelayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683154/android-softkeyboard-enter-the-numeric-value-into-edittext-very-slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems with LayoutParams set to The TableRow, and Views being added to TableRow, try Commenting the setting layout param code and then check the result.

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout1);
            LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                //Log.e("Carlist","Result" +result);
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   int ct_id = json_data.getInt("id");
                   String make = json_data.getString("make");
                   String model = json_data.getString("model");
                   String price = json_data.getString("price");

                   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                         tr.setId(ct_id);
                         tr.setClickable(true);

                         tr.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final View v) {

                                    String sdet_id;
                                    int det_id;
                        //          v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                    det_id = v.getId();
                                    sdet_id = String.valueOf(det_id);
                                    final Intent i = new Intent();
                                    i.setClassName("demo.example.com", "demo.example.com.cardetails");
                                    i.putExtra("Det_id", sdet_id);
                                    startActivity(i);

                          //        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                }
                            });


                              /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
                         ImageView myimage = new ImageView(this);

                         BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
                        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
                        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
                        myimage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                         tr.addView(myimage);
                         TextView tmake=new TextView(this);
                        // tmake.setText(make);
                         tmake.setText(Html.fromHtml("<H1>" + make));
                         tr.addView(tmake); 

                         TextView tmodel=new TextView(this);
                         tmodel.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><H1>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "€" + price + "</b></H1></br></br>" ));
                         tr.addView(tmodel);



                    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
                     //  tr.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
                         tl.addView(tr);
                         View v = new View(this);

                         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51));
                         tl.addView(v);

            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); gives an error "The constructor Tablerow(mainactivity.getdata) is undefined"

Comment: change this line to TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); to TableRow tr = new TableRow(mainactivity.this);

Comment: I've done this, nothing is added to the table, the logs show that items are being added though.